# How to make TTS service to speak at normal speed?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have two sentences, One is long and another is short. The TTS speechRate is et to `1.0f`. But when I make it speak, the long and short sentence is completed at the same time, thus sounding not normal. How can I make the long sentence finish at the same pace at the short sentence or normally?

```
 private fun speakNormally(sentence: String) {
    val speechRate = 1.0f
    val duration = ((sentence.length.toFloat() / (speechRate * 0.005f)).toLong())
    tts?.setSpeechRate(speechRate)
    tts?.speak(sentence, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null)

    Log.d("Tag", "dur: $duration") // duration not used.


}
val sentence = "Short sentence."
val sentenceLong = "A white fox jumped over a brown cat."
```